# How can I access the server running on my machine remotly?

Tags: ubuntu, routes, openvpn

I have a server that is running on my laptop that uses Ubuntu 20.04 and is connected to internet with my home router.

Is there anyway that I can access to my local server from anywhere in the world ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SSH with your public Ip ? If your server has a static ip, it is possible.

This way, you'll access your server from anywhere if you have a terminal.
You can do it like this :

```
ssh user@ip
```

Comment: I have tried to ssh my public ip and i couldn't get access to my server. i have tried also to ping my public ip with no success

Comment: Have you open your ports on your router ? the right ones (22 for ssh, 21 for ftp ...)

Comment: Try with this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/325055/ssh-port-forwarding-from-remote-location-to-computers-on-servers-network), and this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716429/how-to-put-my-server-on-the-internet), they might help you